# Android Studio dialog opening on click

Tags: android

[The dialog in the green circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENLvS.png)

So recently I reinstalled android studio, and after starting the first project I tweaked in some settings but one as far as I remember triggered this dialog. This dialog appears every single time I click an item either on the toolbox or any other ones. If anyone knows the reason behind this please help me out. The dialog appears for 1.5-2 seconds and then fades away.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot it appears that the shortcut to that particular command shows on top telling you that there is a keyboard shortcut for the command you played.Maybe invalidate caches and restart your android should work.do this by going in file and selecting invalidate caches/restart.i hope this helps.